# Cortex-m0+ psr, iepsr, iapsr, and eapsr registers

Tags: assembly, operating-system, arm, cortex-m

In the cortex-m0+ processor, there is a register called the "program status register" (psr for short) that holds 3 important pieces of information:

- The condition flags (zero, carry, etc...), in bits <31:28>
- The exception number, in bits <5:0> (tells you which interrupt is being serviced, == 0 for no interrupt)
- The "Am I in thumb mode" flag, in bit <24>.

As you'd expect, all of these bit fields can be accessed by just reading the psr with an `mrs r0, psr` instruction.  The thing I'm confused about is on [page 16-17 of the m0+ User Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0662b/DUI0662B_cortex_m0p_r0p1_dgug.pdf#page=17).  The manual tells me that I can access, say, ONLY the exception number bits (with all other bits set to zero), by reading the "ipsr" instead of the "psr".  Essentially,

```
    mrs r0, ipsr
```

and

```
    mrs r0, psr
    and r0, r0, #0x3f
```

are identical.

Why are these alternate methods of accessing bitfields in the psr offered?

My best guess is that context-switching or ISR code would want to read ONLY the bottom 6 bits, and this saves a (not very expensive, imo) bitmasking operation.

Comment: to save you from having to mask the bits probably. on the full sized arms, and perhaps here as well, the other direction is more interesting, changing the processor mode svc to irq to ... for example you only want to change those bits so instead of a read-modify-write they let you just write some of the bits (dont have these modes in the cortex-m but these instructions are derived from the big brother versions or look and feel no doubt).  the real answer though is because they wanted to design this in for some reason known to them.

Comment: @dwelch Hmmmm... Can't believe I didn't think of it the other way (writing to the psr).  At any rate, it seems odd that they would pollute an already crammed thumb-2 instruction space just to add these instructions.  It wouldn't kill an os designer to add 2 more instructions in their context-switching routine.  It would be nice to hear perspective from an arm engineer.

Comment: This is a question with no answer.  Would have had to have been either in the brain of the one individual, in the meeting, hallway, conference room, or otherwise if it was between two or more individuals, etc.  And those individuals are likely not permitted to discuss this kind of stuff in public.  Maybe you will get lucky, but most likely not.  Not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: even the 16 bit thumb instruction appears to have some spare bits, would have to examine the other instructions to see if the should be zero means must be zero.  but they could have encoded a feature like this there perhaps.  in the thumb-2 extension, they still have spare bits.  why not add features.  more important though, they already had an mrs instruction why did they need a thumb-2 extension to that?  and if they bothered with that logic then why not parse some of the bits of the instruction to mask some stuff out...

Comment: @dwelch all good points.  Thanks for talking it over with me.  I wasn't sure if it was really a good SO question, but it was bugging the heck out of me and I figured that I might run into some people here who have worked closely with arm engineers or who are arm engineers themselves.

Comment: you might still get lucky, will see...

Comment: even if an answer for this were in the arm docs that doesnt mean that was the real answer, sometimes documented stuff is the opinion of the technical writer and not the designers, sometimes, esp with a company like arm that sells ip, the statements are intentionally wrong (UNPREDICTABLE RESULTS WILL OCCUR) so that they can sue someone later for stealing/sharing their designs (because it really was predictable, just undocumented outside arm).   we could take the majority of the thumb2 extensions and ask the why did you waste logic on this question.  not just mrs.

Comment: @dwelch Thanks for the interesting tidbit about the "UNPREDICTABLE RESULTS WILL OCCUR".  I always thought that was fishy.  Also, I'm not trying to say that the `mrs` instruction is wasted logic.  obviously it's necessary, I'm just trying to say that `mrs rdest, ipsr` might be wasted logic.  but, then again, what's an extra multiplexer in the year 2016?

Comment: re: UNPREDICTABLE RESULTS: in some cases, that leaves the door open for different hardware implementations.  If they want to change the logic that implements something (e.g. to pipeline it more deeply), then they don't have to spend transistors detecting the special case and keeping the same behaviour.  They can just have it behave in whatever way is easiest given the actual implementation.  (e.g. in the NEON `vzip` / `vunzip` instructions, with the same register as src and dst).  x86 is like this too: in most cases of "unpredictable" (e.g. `bsf` on 0), each microarchitecture is predictable.

Comment: absolutely, sometimes it is placeholder, sometimes a real bug, sometimes they had different cores that behaved differently, and sometimes they took advantage of the bug as a legal feature, knowing exactly how it would react in some or all situations, and test for that.  if you go back starting with the printed ARM ARMs to the digital versions you see these come and go, the most interesting is when the were there and then went away. rather than the other way around which is what you would expect.

Comment: now they ship source code instead of mask sets, and dont require you to pass a compatibility test, so it is a bit of a mute point as any individual implementation can either be modified or can have its own bugs from the chip vendor, synthesis, manufacturing, etc.

Answer (score 3):

What I think you're missing is that the `mrs`/`msr` instructions have been around since ARMv**3** well over 20 years ago (when the PC grew from 24 to 32 bits so the other stuff got kicked out of r15 into a special status register). The ARM encodings have always had to differentiate between SPSR vs. CPSR vs. parts of CPSR. When Thumb-2 came along after ARMv6, the Thumb encodings thus also had to differentiate between SPSR vs. CPSR vs. parts of CPSR on ARM1156/Cortex-A.

The point is, then, that there are already bits in those encodings to encode more than one target status register in the classic/A-class architectures - as it happens, there are still a fair few reserved bits spare even after the ARMv7-A virtualisation extensions also added various banked registers to the mix. Now imagine you're designing a new architecture to push your successful embedded ISA/design expertise/development ecosystem into the lower-end microcontroller space, where 8-bit parts dominate and code size and efficiency is *critical*. The question then becomes why would you *not* press those otherwise-unused instruction encoding bits into action to make status register accesses as efficient as they possibly can be?

Comment: That's an interesting point.  The smaller the total code size of the whole firmware, the larger a portion this will be.  Since you're probably always going to need an interrupt handler that checks the exception number, right?  So it makes sense to dedicate an opcode for this (and spend the transistors on decoding it), if I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for exposing some of the interesting history here.  It makes a lot more sense in that context.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the `IPSR` field, you can just use the corresponding (single) instruction.

I think that the second example is just to clarify the behaviour, as this is the CPU which is responsible for masking the data and set all the top bits to 0.